# React-Admin custom data grid expand row event (v3.19)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, react-admin

I'm trying to use react-admin 3.19 following the custom datagrid example.
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/3.19/List.html#expand

I can't manage to get the expand to work. In the example below i added expand button manually myself but can't find how to handle the click event to show the expanded row.

```
const MyDatagridRow = ({ record, resource, id, onToggleItem, children, selected, selectable, basePath }) => (
    <TableRow key={id}>
      {/* first column: selection checkbox */}
      <TableCell padding="none">
        <Checkbox
          disabled={false}
          checked={selected}
          onClick={event => onToggleItem(id, event)}
        />
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell>
          <IconButton
            aria-label="expand row"
            size="small"
            onClick={() => console.log(record)}
          >
            {true ? <ArrowUpward /> : <ArrowDownward />}
          </IconButton>
        </TableCell>
      {React.Children.map(children, field => (
        <TableCell key={`${id}-${field.props.source}`}>
          {React.cloneElement(field, {
            record,
            basePath,
            resource,
          })}
        </TableCell>
      ))}
    </TableRow>
  );
  const DatagridHeader = ({ children }) => (
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell></TableCell>
        {React.Children.map(children, field => (
          <TableCell key={field.props.label}>
            {field.props.label}
          </TableCell>
        ))}
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
  );
  const MyDatagridBody = props => <DatagridBody {...props} row={<MyDatagridRow {...props} selectable={true} />} />;
```

So, is there a way to trigger this manually?

Comment: Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same approach as in the implementation of the react-admin itself. **DatagridRow** implementation uses [useExpanded](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/3.x/packages/ra-core/src/controller/useExpanded.tsx) and as you can see there is action **toggleListItemExpand**. So you can just dispatch this action with resource and id.